# Change the CSS for specific webbrowser

Tags: html, css

I am building a website for my compty, and i need to change the `CSS style` for `Chrome,IE,And Firefox.`

Is there any way to do so? or something like that?

Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you need to change the style based on the browser? Shouldn't the goal be to make it look similar in each browser without having to maintain multiple CSS files?

Comment: Check this JS out: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html . With that loaded, you can check which browser is your visitor using with `BrowserDetect.browser`, that will return the browser's name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no build-in CSS function to specify style for a specific browser. In html, you can do something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
#left {
        margin-left: 4px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also detect the browser with a sripting language such as PHP or ASP, Java or Ruby.

For example, you can do the folowing in PHP:

```
<?php
function isBrowser($name) {
       return strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ucfirst($name)) !== false;
}
```

With that said, I encourage you to avoid specific browser code (css or other) when possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to examine the request header to see if it contains details of the user agent that the request was sent from and use that to decide which css to apply to the response.
This is by no means guaranteed to work, the user agent details in the request can easily be faked or may not be present at all.

Comment: It's much safer and more reliable to use feature detection than rely on the user agent details for the reasons you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/jquery to detect the browser, and then load in the stylesheet you want for that browser.  Just give your link tag for the stylesheet an id, then you can target it with jquery and change the href attribute to the stylesheet you want.

or

You can detect the browser on the server side, a bit less accurate, and set the stylesheet there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite tool for doing this client side: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

It appends a class corresponding to the platform/browser etc . . .